# Redirect on POST request AWS APIGateway and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway endpoint backed by lambda function, as part of that I am returning a redirect to my caller. But in browser what I see is that after POST request, browser sees a 303 response, and then makes a get request to the redirected url (in the network tab), but doesnt actually redirect. i.e. the browser remains on the page via which I had made the initial post request.

Details below

```
POST ENDPOINT

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    DOMAIN = 'https://<my_Api_gateway_address'
    response = {
        "headers": {"Location": DOMAIN+'/success', },
        "statusCode": 303,
    }

    return response
```

Below is the APIGateway's LAmbda Integration

[image]

Below is the javascript code that makes the initial POST request

```
  var url = "https://<my_Api_gateway_endpoint>";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      // Handle the response here if needed
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
```

What do i need to do here to actually redirect to the redirected location on post request?

--- UPDATE ---
I've updated my client side javascript code to below

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(xhr.status);
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
      console.log("DONE");
    }
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
```

Below is the snippet of browser console logs.

[image]

Comment: Can you log all the responseText and status code outside the if condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial request is an AJAX request which follows the redirect automatically (you cannot prevent that, even if you want to). But that has nothing to do with the location of the current browser window. You have to set that manually once the request is finished. You should be able to get the final url with [`xhr.responseURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL)

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)  {
      window.location.href = xhr.responseURL;
    }
  };
```

But just as a remark, this whole process seems a bit fishy. Ie you are doing an AJAX post and then redirecting your browser to the resulting URL of that POST. What if that call requires any special headers? You won't be able to set them.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Not sure why isnt the redirection possible from the API Gateway itself, and needs to be done from the client side. I'd assume this is a rather common use case for a lot of people!

Comment: Because "window location" (ie  what is displayed as URL in the browser's address bar ) and results from AJAX requests are two totally different things and don't have anything to do with each other ...

Answer (score 1):

Just set the value of the `window.location.href`

```js
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.HEADERS_RECEIVED && xhr.status === 200 && xhr.getResponseHeader("Location")) {
      window.location.href = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location")
    }
  };
```

Alternatively, you can just change the response structure of your Lambda so that it would send back `200` and the URL of the payment gateway's checkout page. By doing this, you will be able to simplify the implementation of your client-side code:

```js
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.HEADERS_RECEIVED && xhr.status === 200) {
      var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      window.location.href = jsonResponse.checkoutURL;
    }
  };
```

Comment: xhr.getResponseHeader("Location") is always null. When I print it along with status and reponse text, it shows null everytime.

Comment: @Kraken, can you try this update? Are you able to see the location header in your network logs?

Comment: Its the same. When I am printing all the xhr headers outside if condition it is printing only the headers that it received as part of the second GET request and not the ones that I received as part of the POST request. If I go to the network tab and see the response headers of the POST request, I do see the Location header, but somehow the javascript isnt capturing that and only capturing the responses relevant to the GET request.

Comment: @AllanChua The 200 response is the final response *after* the redirect already took place. This typically won't contain any `Location` header anymore. The `Location` header is only present in the `3xx` (ie the Redirect)  response. But as this is handled internally in the xhr request you can't get hold of that easily

Comment: @derpirscher and how do I capture that? JS code isnt printing any response details relevant to the 3xx response, and only printing 200 response. Do I need to capture that under a different event, i.e. instead of 'xhr.onreadystatechange'?

Comment: @Kraken, do you really have to redirect people from that API? I would recommend to just change the response code of my Lambda to 200 and embed the URL in the response body!

Comment: I am working with a payment gateway, and need to redirect when user clicks on the checkout button.

Comment: @Kraken Yes, but it doesn't mean you have to do it using the built-in behavior of the browser. I also implemented stuff like this using Stripe and AirWallex and its just perfectly fine!

Comment: @AllanChua so you redirected from the client by just sending back the redirected url in the response body and then doing windows.location.href = body.url?

Comment: @Kraken yes bro! that is perfectly fine and the most common way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks a tonne. That works now. But I'm just trying to understand how is the below article doing it withouth having to handle it on the client side. It says in the diagram that the APIGateway would just send the redirected response back.

https://medium.com/@josephmaxmorris7/simple-http-redirects-using-aws-api-gateway-aws-lambda-and-python-dca9ad7a62ad

Comment: @Kraken because in that article he is actually *clicking* the link to the API gateway (ie this link goes into the location bar of the browser window). Then of course the browser also handles redirects. But in your case you are doing an AJAX request ...

Comment: Yeah. Makes sense to me now. My bad, didnt realise that ajax wasnt going to udpate the window by itself!
Thanks a lot!